# Does every set $X$ have a topology for which the only continuous self-surjection is the identity map?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology

This question is a special case of Dominic van der Zypen's question [Reconstructing relations with the image relation of a topology](https://mathoverflow.net/q/214615/1946), as discussed in the comments, particularly the comment of [Eric Wofsey](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214615/reconstructing-relations-with-the-image-relation-of-a-topology#comment-530409), which explains that if the answer to this question is affirmative, then the answer to Dominic's question is also affirmative.

**Question.** Does every set $X$ have a topology for which the only continuous surjection $f:X\to X$ is the identity map?

My answer to Dominic's question shows that for finite sets, the answer is affirmative, since one need only place an order on $X$, and then let the topology be the up-sets of the order. Every continuous surjection is a permutation of $X$ and order-preserving, and hence the identity. Although it is tempting to try to use the same method with well-orders on an infinite set, it doesn't quite work out in that generality, because the predecessor function on the finite height elements (otherwise fixed) will be a continuous surjection, but not the identity.

For an extreme negative answer, I would ask: can one show that there is no topology on a countably infinite set for which the only continuous surjection is the identity map?

Comment: I have a feeling that the rigidity results mentioned in http://mathoverflow.net/a/6300/1946 will be relevant.

Comment: [This question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/188729/strongly-rigid-hausdorff-spaces) also seems related.  In particular, the answer there gives an example with $|X|=\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: [This answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/198738/75) also gives an example whenever $|X|^{\aleph_0}=|X|$.  Still, it seems like this sort of thing is massive overkill and there ought to be some fairly simple construction that always works.

Comment: Very nice question! I think spaces $(X,\tau)$ with the property that the identity is the only continuous self-surjection must have some low separation property: if $x\neq y\in X$ have the property that ${\cal N}_x = {\cal N}_y$ then a continuous self-bijection that swaps $x, y$ can be constructed (if I'm not mistaken).

Answer (score 12):

For $X$ of cardinality at least continuum there exist such spaces, even metrizable ones. It follows immediately from a much more general result, proved by Trnková in [1]. She proves that the category of graphs admits a full embedding into the category of metrizable spaces with nonconstant maps. An inspection of the proof shows that a graph $G$ is sent to a space whose cardinality is $|G|\times\frak{c}$. Then we use the fact that there exist rigid graphs $G$ of every cardinality - this is proved in P. Vopěnka, A. Pultr and Z. Hedrlin, Commentationes Mathematicae Universitatis Carolinae 6(1965), 149-155.

[1] V. Trnková, [Non-constant continuous mappings of metric or compact Hausdorff spaces](https://eudml.org/doc/16494), Comment. Math. Univ. Carolinae 13 (1972) 283–295.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to sketch the construction?

Comment: Note also that you use exactly the rigidity result of Vopěnka, Pultr and Hedrlin to which I had alluded in my comment on the original post!

Comment: @Joel David Hamkins -- One takes a continuum $C$ constructed by Cook (Eric Wofsey points to it in his comment). It has the properties that any map $C\to C$ is either constant or the identity and for every continuum $H\subseteq C$ other than a point and a nonconstant map $f:H\to C$, $f$ is a retraction onto some $K\subseteq H$. Then you pick two distinct points in $C$ (call them initial and terminal) and replace every edge in $G$ with a copy of $C$. I think that this works fine except it does not prevent edges from collapsing. So she introduces two additional rigid continua...

Comment: This is about what I got from the paper. I never read it, just skimmed for this answer. She also cites some preprocessing to reduce the problem to connected graphs without loops but I think that this is not necessary.

Comment: If the embedding in question does not turn any non-surjection into a surjection (don't know whether this is true, but it seems plausible), then the Vopěnka-Pultr-Hedrlin result is unnecessary, and you can just use ordinals (with their strict ordering).

Comment: @AdamPrzeździecki It seems to me that this answer (but using the  Vopěnka-Pultr-Hedrlin result, since well-orders wouldn't work without surjectivity) will also answer Dominic's question at: http://mathoverflow.net/q/215046/1946. Do you agree?

Answer (score 7):

As a very special case, I claim that there is no regular topology on a countably infinite set such that the only contiuous surjection $f:X\rightarrow X$ such that is the identity map. If $X$ is countably and regular, then $X$ is a regular Lindelof space. Since every regular Lindelof space is paracompact, the space $X$ is paracompact and hence completely regular and even realcompact. If $X$ is compact, then $X$ is isomorphic to some countable ordinal $\alpha+1$. Therefore, the mapping $g:\alpha+1\rightarrow\alpha+1$ where $g(n)=n-1$ where $n$ is a finite non-zero ordinal and $g(\beta)=\beta$ where $\beta$ is infinite or zero is a continuous surjection.

Now assume that $X$ is not compact. Recall that a space is compact if and only if it is realcompact and pseudocompact. Therefore, since $X$ is not compact but $X$ is realcompact, the space $X$ is not pseudocompact. Furthermore, the space $X$ is zero-dimensional by the following argument: if $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ and $f:X\rightarrow[0,1]$ is a mapping such that $f(x)=1$ and $f=0$ outside $U$, then the function $f$ is not surjective since $X$ is countable. Therefore, if $r\not\in f[X]$, then $f^{-1}[r,1]$ is a clopen set with
$x\in f^{-1}[r,1]\subseteq U$. Therefore, since $X$ is zero-dimensional but not pseudocompact, by [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/103644/22277), there is a partition of $X$ into infinitely many clopen sets $(C_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Let $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an enumeration of the elements of $X$. Then let $f:X\rightarrow X$ be the mapping where we let $f(x)=x_{n}$ whenever $x\in C_{n}$. Then $f$ is generally a non-identity continuous surjection.

I conjecture that it is consistent with the negation of the continuum hypothesis that every completely regular space of cardinality below the continuum has a non-identity surjection.

Answer (score 3):

In the article *[Constructions and Applications of Rigid Spaces, I](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(78)90006-3)* (Advances in Mathematics **29**, 89--130 (1978), V. Kannan and M. Rajagopalan show that if $(2^{\aleph_0})^+ < 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$, there is a countable space $X$ such that the only non-constant continous self-map is the identity. (Of course that's a notion of rigidity that is "more rigid" than what is asked in the original post.)